# What should get tested in Symfony2 application?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I am confused with the testing of the code on web application (a newbie of testing).
My app is quite simple crud dashboard. I have users, organizations, organization contacts and organization places. User can be assigned an organization, after that he can edit organization info, CRUD contacts and places.

What should get tested in such a application? There is no complex logic here. Controller action gets repository, queries for records, display list, show edit form, save entity. I have few form types, few entities, few security voters.

Should I test each form type, voter, entity with unit test, or should I take more and check the cooperation of all these with functional test?

What at all should be covered by unit test in web application and what by functional test?

Is it worth testing entity getters setters if they have no logic except seting the value?

Comment: It's difficult to say. You can test everything. It's better to use unit test for maintain your project when you will add some features. You can test your output, pages wich you can access or not. There's a lot of possible tests.

Answer (score 3):

> What should get tested in such a application?

Security (*FosUserBundle* configuration?), performances (high volume cases), corner-cases, normal cases.

You want your web application to be secured, fast enough and stable.

> Is it worth testing entity getters setters if they have no logic
>   except seting the value?

You should test your entities when you create them (*Doctrine tags* issues) and when you add some attributes or relations between them (*many-to-many*, etc...).

> What at all should be covered by unit test in web application and what
>   by functional test?

You have to test all the functionalities that you are committed to deliver.

About the unit tests, you should go for specific code you have done.
As an example, you shouldn't need to test the getter generated by *Doctrine* in an entity but if you implement a complex [Doctrine Query using its AST](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/namespace-Doctrine.ORM.Query.AST.html) then you'll need to test it.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Symfony's Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/tests.html), you should firstly test if your pages are successfully loading.

> In computer software, this kind of test is called smoke testing and consists of "preliminary testing to reveal simple failures severe enough to reject a prospective software release".

These are the very first tests I add on every project and, by doing that, I usally find more test to add.